# Yarn timeline server log aggregation

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, timeline

Configuring hadoop 2.7.1 to retain yarn jobs for longer

Have enabled log aggregation and the jobhistory/timeline server and when a job is complete in the resource manager it does show up in the jobhistory server(if you give the correct url), however the jobhistory server is only listing M/R jobs, not yarn applications

The problem is the job is not visible in the timeline server, in fact no jobs show in the timeline server

Current yarn-site.xml configuration :

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.timeline-service.hostname</name>
    <value>host1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.timeline-service.address</name>
    <value>${yarn.timeline-service.hostname}:10200</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.timeline-service.webapp.address</name>
    <value>${yarn.timeline-service.hostname}:8188</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.timeline-service.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.timeline-service.generic-application-history.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.log.server.url</name>
    <value>http://${yarn.timeline-service.hostname}:19888/jobhistory/logs/</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
    <value>/var/vm/apps/hadoop/logs</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>/var/vm/apps/hadoop/logs</value>
</property>
```

Am I providing conflicting configuration in using the jobhistory server AND the timeline server?

At the end of the day I want the yarn logs persisted to hdfs for viewing in the web-ui over the following days/weeks

Comment: Your settings look good. You can also check this article, which describes these settings: http://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set mapreduce.job.emit-timeline-data property to true in mapred-site.xml

This will enable mapreduce jobs to push events to the timeline server.